# Is SSL in Erlang guaranteed to be contained within each process/client/connection?

Tags: security, ssl, functional-programming, erlang

When using software powered by OpenSSL, if past experience is any indication (cough *heartbleed* cough), any client can peek into the private address space of any other client, making SSL not only pointless, but, in fact, counteractive to what it is supposed to accomplish.

What about the SSL in Erlang?

Erlang, being a functional programming language, guarantees that each process/client runs independent each other.

***Does the isolation guarantees extend to SSL in Erlang, or is there some sort of a shared something somewhere?***

Answer (score 0):

Looks like misunderstanding here. SSL/TLS is transport layer. The only thing SSL is made for is for securely transferring data between two sockets. SSL meant to be transparent for application. Erlang and any other language has nothing to do with it's security. Once SSL decrypts data it passes it to the rest of the application in unencrypted form. So it's entirely up to you how to isolate this unencrypted data.

In other words: if you think Erlang is uber-secure language that will somehow magically solve security problems for you - it is not.

Comment: You're completely missing the point.  Adding OpenSSL to an otherwise secure piece of software makes is vulnerable, if history teaches you anything.  Erlang appears to have its own SSL; is it safe to use due to presumably being implemented in Erlang (is it?), or is it no different from OpenSSL?

Comment: Erlang uses OpenSSL. And it's actually a good idea, since fixing one 'standart' implementation is easier than fxing miriad of housegrown ones.

Comment: wait, it does?  so, it means that all those OpenSSL vulnerabilities are applicable to Erlang as well?  oops, that's quite defies the notion that erlang is a functional language, and one process cannot affect the state of another!

Comment: no, it doesnt. Following your logic there are no functional languages. Say, Haskell libraries use OpenSSL too. Scheme? Same story. What else you consider functional?